# .htaccess to RewriteRule or Redirect from one dynamic url domain to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have barely any knowledge of .htaccess but I fumble with code. :)

I have one CMS with 2 domain names, each domain pulls a totally different site but managed through one back end. The sites are related so there is no real secrecy - a parent and a child.

I have one extension that must operate on one domain only. It handles payments through PayPal and PayPal restricts accounts to only one domain per organization. It is used with both domains.

I have relative linking throughout the back end so menu and article links to anything that has to do with that extension carry the domain from which it is generated. I need a way to automatically direct anything from the child site for just that extension to the parent site, both messy and SEF links.

So, here is an example:

```
child.com/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/pcp/info&reset=1&id=1
```

to go to

```
parent.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/pcp/info&reset=1&id=1
```

and

```
child.com/wildcard/wildcard
```

to go to

```
parent.org/wildcard/wildcard
```

The extension is com_civicrm. I need any variables after it to work. These may and may not be ".../pcp/..."

And if this matters, the back end only differs by parent.org/administrator/index.php?option=com_civicrm... so I don't want to accidentally direct the back end to the front end by accidentally losing the "administrator".

Thanks in advance,
Helen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if domain is child.com, and url is '/wildcard/wildcard', redirect to same url on parent.org
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} child\.com$
RewriteRule ^wildcard/wildcard$ http://parent.org/wildcard/wildcard [R=302,L]

# if domain is child.com, and querystring contains 'option=com_civicrm', redirect to same url on parent.org
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} child\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_civicrm
RewriteRule (.*) http://parent.org/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Happy fumbling :-)

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but let me ask one more question. For the wildcard redirect, if I get the SEF to be something like parent.org/donate-*/* with the wildcard being anything after the - and may or maynot have /, is there a way to code that so I don't have to build a ReWriteRule for each instance? With careful SEF planning, I can do this :)

Comment: the second fox for SEF is not working correctly. If I use it when there is no more characters after "donate", it doesn't change the domain. If I use it when there are characters after "donate", like "donate-this-page", I get a "The page isn't redirecting properly" error in my FireFox browser. :(

Comment: "donate" with no characters following it does not work properly.